# Thousand days of Latin Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion

A moment ago we reached the benchmark of 1000 days in beta.
Many thanks to all of you for participation!

I hope that the site will continue to thrive and will eventually graduate.
To that end, I would be happy to hear your thoughts.
**How have the first thousand days been?**
Are you particularly happy or unhappy about something?
Is there something you would like to add or remove?
**What has this site given to *you*?**

For the current number of days in beta and other statistics, see [our Area 51 page](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75409/latin-language).

Comment: currently 2.1 questions per day... how on Earth will we get to 10 per day? Unless Latin becomes super popular again, that will be hard...

Comment: @luchonacho Ten questions per day doesn't seem necessary, but about five are needed, judging by the statistics of graduated sites. Either way, we'll have to double the question flux.

Comment: If you find the secret to double the number of questions per day, please share it with the [Spanish.SE] community! :-)

Answer (score 16):

Given my experience in multiple SE sites, this is by far the most friendly one. Getting an upvote for Q or A on other sites (stackoverflow, math, unix, stats, ELU, to name a few) is very difficult. Meanwhile, religious sites are super defensive and hostile to outsiders. And there are so many haters all over the SE network.

Thus, relatively speaking, this site is a safe haven. I'm always happy to come back. My relatively high reputation is only a reflection of how kind you are, and by no means represents how good my Latin is (which is not).

Comment: I'm very glad to hear this. The welcoming atmosphere is something that I – and no doubt others as well – have been striving for. Thanks for sharing this experience!

Comment: Yay! Perhaps it is because we are still a young website. Perhaps we will turn into grumpy old devils eventually...